# I am trying to build a map selection that only lets you enter a url when a choice is made

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am using Meteor and Iron Router, most things are working, I have successfully got the page to redirect back to home when visiting /spirit, however I want the redirect to stop working when a selection on the map is made.

I may not be approaching this correctly. You will see below in the BC1 click function what I want to happen.

Here is my MAP.js code below

```
function map(){
  Template.map.rendered = function(){
    var s = Snap("#map");

  //  var snap = Snap(912,912);






    Snap.load("/map.svg", function (f) {

      var el = f.select("path#Fill-65");//Alberta

      var BC = f.selectAll("path#Fill-112 , path#Fill-94");// All BC

      var BC1 = f.select("path#Fill-112");// BC 1

      var BC2 = f.select("path#Fill-94");//BC 2

      var SK = f.select("path#Fill-114");//Saskatchewan

      var MB = f.select("path#Fill-117");//MANITOBA

      var QB = f.select("path#Fill-116");//QUEBEC

      var ON = f.select("path#Fill-120");//ONTARIO

      var T1 = f.select("path#Fill-115");//T1








      var filterMap = s.paper.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(-2, 0, 3, '#000', '0.5'));

      var filterMapNone = s.paper.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(0, 0, 0));

      BC1.hover(function(){
        allBcOn();
      }, function() {
        allBcOff();
      });


      BC1 .click(function(){
        alert("Enter You West Coaster");
        enter = "false";
        /////SEND TO NEXT PAGE//////
      });


      function allBcOn(){
        BC.forEach( function(elem,i) {
           elem.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
           elem.attr({filter: filterMap });
        });
      }

      function allBcOff(){
        BC.forEach( function(elem,i) {
           elem.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);
           elem.attr({filter: undefined });
        });
      }




      el.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        el.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        el.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         el.attr({filter: undefined });
         el.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      SK.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        SK.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        SK.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         SK.attr({filter: undefined });
         SK.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      MB.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        MB.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        MB.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         MB.attr({filter: undefined });
         MB.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      QB.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        QB.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        QB.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         QB.attr({filter: undefined });
         QB.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      ON.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        ON.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        ON.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         ON.attr({filter: undefined });
         ON.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      T1.hover(function(){
        //el.attr({fill: "#000"});
        T1.animate({fill: "#fff"},500);
        T1.attr({filter: filterMap });
      }, function() {
         T1.attr({filter: undefined });
         T1.animate({fill: "#C2C2C2"},500);

      });

      g = f.select("g");

      s.append(g);


    });
  }
```

**

> UPDATE

**

This is my new code. For Iron Router. I dont know where to put the map.js click function for it to work, and when I visit /spirit I get the error below the new code. The /sprit page should send you back to the home page unless you have made a click action on the bcClick.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',

  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('postsList', {path: '/spirit'});
  this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/spirit/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
  this.route('login', {path: '/login'});
});


Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'postPage'}); //Show all data when post ID is oncorrect in URL
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (Session.get("enter") === true) {
        this.render('home');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, { only: ['postsList'] });
```

Error

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Router.onBeforeAction.only (http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?4e5fa4c0e6dac39de81308142d50f13543d19152:26:14)
    at RouteController.runHooks (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:843:16)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:2302:14
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:302:14)
    at Tracker.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:430:14)
```

UPDATE NUMERO TWO

I have a semi working example and router code the way I was expecting. My only issue is when visiting/spirit a refresh redirects you, I want the browser session to remember when the user has clicked the link and allow after the first click to view the page antytime.

You can visit the site [here](http://nt-dev.cf) to see what I mean.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',

  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('homePage', {path: '/'});
  this.route('postsList', {path: '/spirit'});
  this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/spirit/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
  this.route('login', {path: '/login'});
  this.route('landing', {path: '/landing'});
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'postPage'}); //Show all data when post ID is oncorrect in URL
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){


  var enter = Session.get("enter");
  if (typeof enter != "undefined" && enter === true) {
    alert("welcome");
    this.render('postsList')
  } else {
    this.redirect('homePage');

  }


}, {only: 'postsList'}); //Show all data when post ID is oncorrect in URL

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  //Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

  Template.homePage.events({
    'click a': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set("enter", true);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: As far as I can say, your "enter" variable is defined both in global and local namespace, thus your change won't be reflected.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to what  I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should rewrite that code to make full use of Iron Router onBeforeAction.

Here's some example code that you might want to use as a reference. I haven't tested it though. Here's the relevant part of the router:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/spirit', function() {
    this.render('postsList');
});

Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (Session.get("enter") === true) {
        this.render('home');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, { only: ['postsList'] });
```

And in your BC event you should do something like:

```
BC1 .click(function(){
    alert("Enter You West Coaster");
    Session.set('enter', false);
    /////SEND TO NEXT PAGE//////
});
```

This should give you a pointer at how you should structure the routing.

**UPDATE**

I've reduced your problem to an example. Try this out:

meteor-test-map.html

```
<head>
  <title>meteor-test-map</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="layout">
Main layout
  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="postsList">
Posts list
<button>Click Me</button>
</template>

<template name="spirit">
Spirit
</template>

<template name="home">
Home
</template>

<template name="loading">
Loading
</template>
```

meteor-test-map.js

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',

  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('postsList', {path: '/spirit'});
  this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/spirit/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
  this.route('login', {path: '/login'});
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'postPage'}); //Show all data when post ID is oncorrect in URL

Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    var enter = Session.get("enter");
    if (typeof enter != "undefined" && enter === true) {
        this.render('home');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, { only: ['postsList'] });


Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

  Template.postsList.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set("enter", true);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  Meteor.publish("posts", function() {
    return Posts.find();
  });
}
```

Comment: How do I deal with the global and local namescope. the BC1click event is accesbile iron router?

Comment: I guess how do I run the map javscript before the if statement?

Comment: Sorry Im even more confused now. I am trying to have the home page have the click event handler, and then that take you to the postsList template at /spirit. I am not sure why there is a button on the postsList template, when I visit /spirit which is supposed to redirect you to home I still get the same mentioned error above.

Comment: I am going to choose your answer, because I have learned alot playing with it. Thanks. FYI I have tried a simpler solution, but still having a little issue you can view it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690859/how-to-change-a-session-value-after-a-click-event-so-that-a-page-refresh-does-n